# how to show an image field's value in the show form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I got my create, update and show forms working for a single entity. One of the fields is an image file that I am entering using the multipart attribute in the form. My question is how do I show the image attribute in the show form.

```
<tr>
 <th>Photo</th>
 <td><%= @teacher.photo %></td>
</tr>
```

The photo attribute is of binary type in the table definition.

```
create_table :teachers do |t|

   t.string :firstname, null: false
   t.string :lastname, null: false
   t.string :email, null: false
   t.string :cellphone
   t.string :username, null: false
   t.string :password_digest, null: false
   t.string :addr_streetno
   t.integer :addr_aptno
   t.string :addr_city
   t.string :addr_state
   t.integer :addr_zip
   t.binary :photo, :limit => 0.5.megabyte

   t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: [Store images in the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)?

Answer (score 2):

we can display images as Thumbnails by using carrier wave gem

```
<%= image_tag @teacher.photo_url(:thumb) if @teacher.photo? %>
```